# Time dependent perturbation theory applied to energy levels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, time-evolution

I am reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5116) paper and in deriving equations 6/7 and 11/12 they claim to use second oder time dependent perturbation theory (TDPT) in order to get the correction to the energy levels. Can someone point me towards some reading about that? In the QM textbooks I used, for TDPT they just calculate the change in population as a function of time, but I have never seen a formula for the change in energy levels. Thank you!

Comment: found this https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/07%3A_Approximation_Methods/7.04%3A_Perturbation_Theory_Expresses_the_Solutions_in_Terms_of_Solved_Problems

Comment: @annav but this seems to be time independent perturbation theory

Comment: true , found also this https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/13%3A_Molecular_Spectroscopy/13.11%3A_Time-Dependent_Perturbation_Theory

Comment: @annav yes, but they talk only about the population transfer (both of the links you posted contain what is found in classic QM textbooks). What I am asking about is the change in energy levels when using time dependent perturbation theory (not change in population)

Comment: this is too theoretical for me. maybe you should ask your question at https://physicsoverflow.org/  which a lot of theorists check

Comment: @annav seems like they don't allow new users there, so I can't post the question

Comment: It does say, for new users "try again soon".

Comment: @annav yeah, so until they allow new users I can't post (I don't have an account there)